# Formula Help with multiple if and functions

Tags: formula

Does anyone see what is wrong with this formula?
The error was just invalid syntax, no ( error or anything.
I am trying to take a predictive score and a lead score and create a combined bucket, so for instance if the predictive score is >= 90 AND a App Secc score is >= 90 then apply a grade of A

```
IF(
ISBLANK(NF_LS_PredictiveModelTotalScore_c),
NULL,
IF(
AND(
NF_LS_PredictiveModelScore_c >= 75,
NF_LSAppSecPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSInfoSecurityPersonScore__c >= 30
), 
"A",
IF(
AND(
NF_LSPredictiveModelTotalScore_c >= 15,
NF_LSAppSecPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSInfoSecurityPersonScore__c >= 30
), 
"B",
IF(
AND(
NF_LSPredictiveModelTotalScore_c >= 96,
NF_LSITPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSITManagementPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSITOperationsPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSSoftwareDevPersonScore__c >= 30
), 
"A",
IF(
AND(
NF_LSPredictiveModelTotalScore_c >= 75,
NF_LSITPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSITManagementPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSITOperationsPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSSoftwareDevPersonScore__c >= 30
), 
"B",
IF(
AND(
NF_LSPredictiveModelTotalScore_c >= 45,
NF_LSITPersonScore__c >= 70,
NF_LSITManagementPersonScore__c >= 70,
NF_LSITOperationsPersonScore__c >= 70,
NF_LSSoftwareDevPersonScore__c >= 70
) ,
"B",
IF(
AND(
NF_LS_PredictiveModelTotalScore_c >= 45,
NF_LSITPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSITManagementPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSITOperationsPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSSoftwareDevPersonScore__c >= 30
), 
"C",
IF(
AND(
NF_LSPredictiveModelTotalScore_c >= 15,
NF_LSITPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSITManagementPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSITOperationsPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSSoftwareDevPersonScore__c >= 30
), 
"C",
IF(
AND(
NF_LSPredictiveModelTotalScore_c <= 15,
NF_LSITPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSITManagementPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSITOperationsPersonScore__c >= 30,
NF_LSSoftwareDevPersonScore__c >= 30
), 
“D”,
NULL
)))))))))
```

Comment: What is the desired behavior? What is the actual behavior? What, if any, error message do you receive? Please make an [edit] to add details to help the community help you.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. The error was just invalid syntax, no ( error or anything. I am trying to take a predictive score and a lead score and create a combined bucket, so for instance if the predictive score is >= 90 AND a App Secc score is >= 90 then apply a grade of A

Answer (score 0):

```
“D”,
```

These are "smart quotes", probably accidentally copied from a Microsoft Office editor (which is why you should never use them for coding!). Make sure you're using straight quotes:

```
"D",
```

This formula could otherwise be optimized, but this is likely your main problem.

Comment: Thank you, I am sure this could be optimized but being a beginner with formulas in Salesforce this is the best I could come up with. Still learning so any tips would be great. I will use text editor moving forward, thanks for that tip